# How to send automated SMS messages over the internet?

Tags: internet, sms, api

Does anyone know of a service that will send SMS messages over the internet, and can be automated?

Prefer service to:

- Be free
- Have an API freely available and highly modular
- Be open source

Like to avoid:

- Expensive
- No API, must only use their system.
- No Customization

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean "Short Message Service" (as in cellular phone text messaging)?

Comment: Yes, I want to sends automated texts, using some service that I can then program to.

Comment: There's definitely noo way anyone would try and exploit such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

I knew of a professional service that required the end user to define their carrier, and then they converted it to the built-in email address (EX: Verizon is <10-digit phone number>@vtext.com)

I found a (non-confirmed) list of many of the carriers here:

> ATT - [10-digit phone number] @ txt.att.net
>
> Sprint - [10-digit phone number] @ messaging.sprintpcs.com
>
> T-Mobile - [10-digit phone number] @ tmomail.net
>
> US Cellular - [10-digit phone number] @ email.uscc.net
>
> Verizon - [10-digit phone number] @ vtext.com

[How do you send a text message from the computer?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080722092718AALtjzx)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway)

Comment: Wow this is really good!  The only problem with this is that I don't know what carrier the number I'm sending to has.

Comment: Yes indeed this requires the user to define their carrier before it's useful ... unless you can determine the carrier based on the phone number (anyone know if there's an API to do that? :)

Answer (score 3):

[Zeep Mobile](http://zeepmobile.com/) is a free service, and I think it's pretty good. I'm planning on using it for a project in the near future.

Comment: I like the idea, but this service seems a little too controlling for what I am doing.  I don't want to force my users to sign up through a web page.  Nominally I want to be able to specify a number and the message, and that's it.

Comment: They recently sent out a news email including a section saying "Users can now subscribe to your app via SMS in addition to using the Zeep Mobile panel." So maybe it's a non-issue now?

Answer (score 0):

You can script PHP to do this by sending email to phone#@carrieraddress.com. Here is a list of the email format for different carriers:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway

You can write a script and then use a cron job or service scheduler to automate the messages.